# Get parameters of an URL in python when rendering a notebook with voila

Tags: python, cgi, url-parameters, voila

I would like to parse all the parameters and query string of an URL rendered with voila python:

[https://flyingcars.org/john/voila/render/shared/users/john/lrn_url.ipynb?dossier=SA12345678&autorun=True&name=jose&dossier=SA123445#{whatever='no',other='UK'}](https://flyingcars.org/john/voila/render/shared/users/john/lrn_url.ipynb?dossier=SA12345678&autorun=True&name=jose&dossier=SA123445#%7Bwhatever=%27no%27,other=%27UK%27%7D)

So far I have:

```
URL_BASE = os.environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME')
PARAMETERS = os.environ.get("QUERY_STRING")
print(f'{URL_BASE=}')
print(f'{PARAMETERS=}')
```

I would get:

```
URL_BASE='flyingcars.org/john/voila/render/shared/users/john/lrn_url.ipynb'
PARAMETERS='dossier=SA12345678&autorun=True&name=john'
```

but I have two questions:

a) how to get the rest of the parameters after # in the URL

b) Is there a standard library to get the query in form of a dictionary

What i tried:

I am trying to use cgi module in this way:

```
variables  = cgi.FieldStorage()
variables2 = dict(cgi.FieldStorage())
ks = cgi.FieldStorage().keys()
print(f'{ks=}')
vs = cgi.FieldStorage().values() # error here
for key in cgi.FieldStorage().keys():
    print(key)
    print(fieldStorage[key].value) # error here
   
print(f'{variables=}')
print(f'{variables2=}')
```

this gives me an error in fieldStorage[key].value, and converting cgi.FieldStorage() into dict() does not work properly.

And these give errors:

```
print(fieldStorage[key].value)
```

And the previous line

```
fieldStorage().values()
```

Of  I can hack around strings but there might be a straight way to get the variables in a dict with cgi.
In cgi I can not get a way to get the parameters beyond the # symbol in the URL.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that part after `#` is sent to server at all.

Comment: I comment it out because it gives error.